# Returning an array from a Cdef function

Tags: python, arrays, cython

I want to make a pure function in c-style which take an array as an argument (pointer) and do something with it. But I cannot find out how to define an array argument for a cdef function. Here is some toy code I have made.

```
cdef void test(double[] array  ) except? -2:
  cdef int i,n
  i = 0
  n = len(array)
  for i in range(0,n):
     array[i] = array[i]+1.0



def ctest(a):
   n = len(a)
   #Make a C-array on the heap.
   cdef double *v
   v = <double *>malloc(n*sizeof(double))
   #Copy in the python array
   for i in range(n):
      v[i] = float(a[i])
   #Calling the C-function which do something with the array
   test(v)
   #Puttint the changed C-array back into python
   for i in range(n):
      a[i] = v[i]
   free(v)
   return a
```

The code will not compile. Have search for how to define C-arrays in Cython, but have not found how to do it. The double[] array does clearly not not work. Have also tried with:

```
cdef void test(double* array  ) except? -2:
```

I can manage to do the same in pure c, but not in cython:(

```
   D:\cython-test\ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
   Compiling ctest.pyx because it changed.
   [1/1] Cythonizing ctest.pyx

   Error compiling Cython file:
   ------------------------------------------------------------
   ...
   from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

   cdef void test(double[] array):
       cdef int i,n
       n = len(array)
                   ^
   ------------------------------------------------------------

   ctest.pyx:5:17: Cannot convert 'double *' to Python object

   Error compiling Cython file:
   ------------------------------------------------------------
   ...
   from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

   cdef void test(double[] array):
       cdef int i,n
       n = len(array)
       for i in range(0,len(array)):
                                ^
   ------------------------------------------------------------

   ctest.pyx:6:30: Cannot convert 'double *' to Python object
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "setup.py", line 10, in <module>
       ext_modules = cythonize("ctest.pyx"),
     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line           877, i
   n cythonize
       cythonize_one(*args)
     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 997, i
   n cythonize_one
       raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
   Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: ctest.pyx

   E:\GD\UD\Software\BendStiffener\curvmom>
```

**UPDATE:**

Have updated my code after all advices and it compiles now:) But my array do still not update. I will expect that all entries should be updated with 5.0, but they do not

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef void test(double[] array):
    cdef int i,n
    n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(double)
    for i in range(0,n):
        array[i] = array[i]+5.0

def ctest(a):
    n = len(a)
    #Make a C-array on the heap.
    cdef double* v
    v = <double*>malloc(n*sizeof(double))
    #Copy in the python array
    for i in range(n):
        v[i] = float(a[i])
    #Calling the C-function which do something with the array
    test(v)
    #Puttint the changed C-array back into python
    for i in range(n):
        a[i] = v[i]
    free(v)
    for x in a:
        print x
    return a
```

Here are a python test program for testing my code:

```
import ctest
a = [0,0,0]
ctest.ctest(a)
```

So there is still something I am doing wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: You have to post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

`len()` is a python function that works only on python objects. This is why it won't compile.
For a C-array you could replace `n=len(array)` by  `n = sizeof(array) / sizeof(double)`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [typed memoryviews](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) and the buffer interface. These provide a nice interface to array like data structures like those underlying numpy arrays, but can also be used to work with C arrays. From the documentation:

> For example, they can handle C arrays and the Cython array type ([Cython arrays](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#view-cython-arrays)).

In your case this might help:

```
cdef test(double[:] array) except? -2:
    ...
```

The `double[:]` allows all 1d double arrays to be passed to the function. Those can then be modified. As the `[:]` defines a memoryview, all changes will be made in the array you created the memoryview on (the variable you passed as the parameter to `test`).

Comment: I will look into that